# Django: Annotate missing dates

Tags: django, django-orm

I want to know how many orders I got per day in a specific period.

My Order model looks like that:

```
class Order(models.Model):

...
    bookingdate         = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
...
```

My current Django "query" looks like that:

```
query = Order.objects.filter(bookingdate__gte=startdate, bookingdate__lte=enddate)
query = query.annotate(created_date=TruncDate('bookingdate')).values('created_date').annotate(
            sum=Count('created_date')).values('created_date', 'sum')
```

My current problem is that I only get dates listed where at least one order happend per day. But I want also to list the dates with 0 orders.

For example I get right now a "list" like that:

```
12.12.2018 => 3
14.12.2018 => 1
17.12.2018 => 2
```

But I also want the dates in between. Example:

```
12.12.2018 => 3
13.12.2018 => 0
14.12.2018 => 1
15.12.2018 => 0
16.12.2018 => 0
17.12.2018 => 2
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Did you achieve this? I'm trying to do something in the same lines.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I am processing this "manually" in my python code.

Answer (score -3):

You have a typo in your code

Replace

```
query = Order.objects.filter(bookingdata__gte=startdate, bookingdate__lte=enddate)
```

With

```
query = Order.objects.filter(bookingdate__gte=startdate, bookingdate__lte=enddate)
```

Comment: this should have been posted as a comment, not an answer to the question